# PhpMyAdmin Merging two tables

Tags: mysql, join, merge, phpmyadmin

I have Table one and Table two. Table one has columns zoe and clo, but table two has oez and olc and it goes like this zoe=oez and cloe=olc how can I merge them?

Comment: Then aren't both tables equal?

Comment: You want the primary keys of table 1 to be equivalent to the primary keys of table 2? Or do you want to merge table 1 and table 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but using `union all` can merge the results into as single table. You would have to, however, create a new primary key if this is going to be a permanent table.

```
Select a.id as id, a.value as value
From a
UNION ALL
Select b.id1 as id, b.value1 as value
From b
Group by id, value
```

Example:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/093e1/4